# node-sspi keep on asking for authentication after deploying on Azure

Tags: node.js, azure, iis

I'm working on an application, building front end using angular and back end using node JS. For authentication, since we have to go with windows authentication, i chose Node-sspi as it is simple to implement and found it effective. Below i'm posting a simple code similar to the code i'm working with.

```
var http = require('http');
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    var nodeSSPI = require('node-sspi')
    var nodeSSPIObj = new nodeSSPI({
      retrieveGroups: true
    })
    nodeSSPIObj.authenticate(req, res, function(err){
      res.finished || next()
    })
})

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var out =
    'Hello ' +
    req.connection.user +
    '! Your sid is ' +
    req.connection.userSid +
    ' and you belong to following groups:<br/><ul>'
  if (req.connection.userGroups) {
    for (var i in req.connection.userGroups) {
      out += '<li>' + req.connection.userGroups[i] + '</li><br/>\n'
    }
  }
  out += '</ul>'
  res.send(out)
})

app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log('server is listening on port '+port);
})

console.log('Your application is listening on port '+port);
```

When i browse this on local, i'm able to do the authentication part and can see the landing page. 
the problem is when i deploy it on azure or on IIS it is keep on asking me for the authentication.

Please let me know how to achieve windows authentication using node-sspi on IIS and Azure.

Comment: Could you please tell me which Azure service you have used now? Azure VM or Web apps? Is your server and your client in the same domain?

Comment: I'm using Azure web apps here. my both client and server are on same domain, basically it's a node js application which inturn uses angular as front end, both are on same server.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it's not possible to use windows authentication in Azure web apps. App Service PaaS VM instance(s) can't be domain joined. This is the reason why you always ask you login in.

Azure Active Directory is the best option. Sync from AD to Azure Active Directory is also quite easy to setup.

If you still want to absolutely use Windows auth and host your website on Azure, you can create Windows VM and host your website there. You then need to join the VM to your AD. To do this, both VMs must be in the same network.

Comment: Accepted. but i'm not sure, why the same issue on IIS. if i try to host the application locally on IIS it shows the same.

Comment: Can we implement windows authentcation without LDAP using passport. Can you please share your thoughts.

Comment: This seems a issue with the iisnode in the IIS, See this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/issues/658). I suggest you could try to create a new issue, it seems to be related with the iisnode in IIS.

Comment: Did you get any solution for this? and how did you achieve the windows authentication without using LDAP in node js

Answer (score 0):

Please add the site to **Trusted sites**:

[image]